# How to check if two list of string are similar

Tags: text

I would like to ask you how to check if two or more list of strings are similar to each other. For example, `{"Obama is the President of the United States", "Michelle is wife's president", "I live in Europe",...}` and `{"Cary is in North Carolina", "I like American people", "I would like to visit the United States"}` in Mathematica?
What I would like to do is to create two different lists with element/strings inside, and check if there is similarity between the elements stored in each list. 
For example, I would like to check the similarity between `"Obama is the President of the United States"` and `"I live in Europe"` (I should got 0), but also between `"Obama is the President of the United States"` (list 1) and `"I would like to visit the United States"` (list 2). 
How could I do this?

Comment: Is the similarity based on the number of words shared between the two sentences? Does the order of the words matter at all? What value would be output by the last comparison you mention? Ultimately, it would be good to specify as best as possible what formula should be used to calculate the similarity. As a starting point, you might use something like `StringSplit` to split each sentence into a list of words and use `Intersection` to find which words are common to both lists. Maybe `Length[Intersection[StringSplit[sentence1], StringSplit[sentence2]]]`?

Comment: This is a topic of natural language processing.
vectorizing the text as an N-gram and then using distance metric such as cosine similarity.
there is a [neural network example](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/NeuralNetRepository/resources/BERT-Trained-on-BookCorpus-and-English-Wikipedia-Data) exactly what you want do.(check `Sentence analogies`)

Comment: Thank you Mass Defect and Xminer. Yes, I was thinking about the number of words between sentences. No, the order would not matter. The value of the last sentences would be greater than 0.

Comment: @math.world, You can also use `SmithWatermanSimilarity` and `EditDistance` (or any of the similiar functions) to get what you want.